# How to use SQLAlchemy to create a temp table for MSSQL?

Tags: sql-server, sqlalchemy

I've tried the following method of creating a temp table for MSSQL using SQLA:

```
    table_name = "#foo"
    meta = MetaData(bind = session.bind)
    table = Table(quoted_name(table_name, quote=False),
                  meta,
                  Column('a_number', Integer),
                  Column('device_Id', Integer),
                  Column('cost', Integer)
                  )

    table.create()
```

There are no errors when I execute this, but there are errors if I follow it up with SQL statements that try to access the table. (The errors indicate #foo doesn't exist)

Also, if I look at the temp tables in my MSSQL session, there's no mention of the table, further evidence that it doesn't exist.

Note that I don't think this is a connection issue - if I comment out the above table.create() and 'manually' create the table, as in session.execute("create #foo..") that succeeds and so does the subsequent insert and read. So I think  I'm on the same connection the whole time. Also, I can single step through this in a debugger and intermittently request my MSSQL session ID and it comes back the same (meaning I'm on the same session from MSSQL's point of view too)

A later test: I enabled full SQLAlchemy debugging and I noticed that it table.create() was causing a "commit" to be issued after the create table statement. Somehow, this commit was causing the temp table to become inaccessible. I experimented and found that if this commit is not emitted, then table.create() works and the temp table can be accessed in subsequent statements.

Here's my "work around" until I figure out why the commit is being emitted and/or why the commit is causing the temp table to "go away":

```
    table_name = "#foo"
    meta = MetaData(bind = session.bind)
    table = Table(quoted_name(table_name, quote=False),
                  meta,
                  Column('a_number', Integer),
                  Column('device_Id', Integer),
                  Column('cost', Integer)
                  )

    session.execute(CreateTable(table))
```

In the above approach, CreateTable is returning the actual SQL creation syntax and it's then executed via session.execute (which does not issue a commit)

Answer (score 2):

A couple of points:
-> Check if you are creating engine properly. Check the link and look for Microsoft SQL Server heading. Link: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/engines.html
-> Check if your metadata is bounded to the engine.

Comment: We are using a connection string, which does contain the apparently important part of "mssql+pyodb"

"mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=DRIVER={FreeTDS};TDS_Version=8.0;SERVER=XXX;PORT=1433;UID=XXX;PWD=XX;DATABASE=XXX"

My metadata.bind has a reference to an Engine object that appears to be valid..ie it's url field contains the connection string above...

Comment: Please don't splatter code in comments. They are useless as the formatting is not robust enough.

Comment: Update the question?